# Deployment without IaaS and SaaS

Tags: machine-learning

I have always seen ML deployments either on SaaS like Heroku or IaaS like AWS
What the courses don't cover are deployment on a company's own servers.
That's exactly my case wherein the company for whatever reasons don't want to get their data on the cloud.
What deployment options do I have?

Comment: custom deployment options can be so varied as the people needing them, so no book can possibly cover them. What did you try?

Comment: @NikosM. I haven't tried anything but I wish to. Hence wanting to leverage the community experience